# How can I separate data with typecasting in an array?

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting

I want to add 2 different types in the same array of size 100x4. In the first column I want to add names of foods(with use of pointers) and in the second and third some numbers such as calories and hour of eating **(with typecasting).**

I've been trying for this many days but I cannot find any solution. Is there a way to fix this with typecasting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *table[100][4];
    int n=0;
    int j;
    for (j=0;j<4;j++){
        if (j==0){
            printf ("Add your food:\n");
            scanf("%c",&table[n][j]);
        }else if (j==1){

            printf ("Add calories:\n");
            (float) *table[n][j];
            scanf("%d",&table[n][j]);

        }else if (j==2){
            (float) *table[n][j];
            printf ("Add the time you ate:\n");
            scanf("%.2f",&table[n][j]);
        }else if (j==3){
            printf ("Kati\n");
        }
    }
    for (j=0;j<4;j++){
        if (j==0){
            printf ("food:%c",&table[n][j]);
        }else if (j==1){
                        (float) *table[n][j];

            printf ("calories:%f",*table[n][j]);
        }else if (j==2){
                        (float) *table[n][j];

            printf ("time you ate:%f",*table[n][j]);
        }else if (j==3){
            printf ("Kati\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a union as array members, that's what it is for

Comment: @Ctx I said only with typecasting

Comment: You can principally use char arrays to store arbitrary types, provided the arrays are properly aligned. The thing is that you have an array of char *pointers* pointing to nothing.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Technically, it is undefined behaviour however and it might break on some platforms

Comment: I think you need to learn a bit more about type casting. I think you are under the impression that all those `(float) *table[n][j];` statements do something useful, but they actually just convert a `char` value stored at `*table[n][j]` into a `float` value. They so not change the storage type of the `*table[n][j]` location. Besides that `*table[n][j]` is an uninitialized pointer, so doesn't actually point to any valid location.

Comment: @Ctx I thought that char arrays are an exception to that rule. For example you may want to write your own heap with a fixed size. That could be a static char array which you use to return properly aligned chunks from. You have to define the memory as *some*thing.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The other way is correct: You can access any object through a pointer to char, but not the other way round

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple different pieces of data that you want to treat as a unit, you would use a `struct` for that and have an array of structs.

You can define the struct as:

```
struct food {
    char name[50];
    int calories;
    float time;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
struct food table[100];
int n=0;

for (n=0; n<100; n++) {
    printf ("Add your food:\n");
    scanf("%49s",table[n].name);

    printf ("Add calories:\n");
    scanf("%d",&table[n].calories);

    printf ("Add the time you ate:\n");
    scanf("%f",&table[n].time);
}

for (n=0; n<100; n++) {
    printf("food:\n");
    printf("  name: %s\n", table[n].name);
    printf("  calories: %d\n", table[n].calories);
    printf("  time: %.2f\n", table[n].time);
}
```

Comment: This is indeed what the OP actually wants to do.